# $\; C^3_{loc}$-Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations

Let $\;f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^m\;$ be a bounded function which satisfies the following pde:

$\;\Delta f - G_f(f)=0\;$ where $\;G\in C^2(\mathbb R^m;\mathbb R_{+})\;$ and $\;G_f=(\frac {\partial G}{\partial f_1}, \dots, \frac {\partial G}{\partial f_m})^{T}\;$

Furthermore for $\;f\;$ holds:

"$\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to f_1(x_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$ in $\;C^3_{loc}(\mathbb R^2;\mathbb R^m)\;$ by linear elliptic estimates"

**I'm trying to understand what exactly the last sentence means.**

I have no clue how this limit follows, so I'm guessing $\; C^3_{loc}$-convergence should be the key here. I haven't seen this kind of convergence before. *What is the norm in this case?*

In addition, *are these "linear elliptic estimates" related somehow to pde?*

I have trouble getting my head around this phrase, so any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the claim that "if $f$ solves this PDE, and $f$ has this other property, then $f_1$ is also a solution to the same PDE"?  Or is it that "because $f$ solves this PDE, the translates of $f$ converge to $f_1$"?  Perhaps something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but I'm not sure this answers your question.  I can only give some introduction to two of the pieces that might be confusing, but I don't understand your question enough to answer it.

**Convergence in $C^3_{loc}$**

First, I can explain what $C^3_{loc}$ convergence means.  We say that a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $C^3_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ if for every compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$,
$$
\sup_{|\alpha|\leq 3, x\in K} |\partial_\alpha f_n - \partial_\alpha f| < \epsilon.
$$
In other words, if for every compact set $K$, the function and all its derivatives (up to third order) converge uniformly.

So the statement that $f(x_1+y_1,x_2)\to f_1(x_1,x_2)$ in $C^3_{loc}$ as $y_1\to\infty$ means that, as one slides the function $f$ left, the behavior "near the origin" stabilizes.  As an example of how this could happen, consider the function 
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \sin(x_2) + (1+|x_1|^2)^{-1}.
$$
The functions $f(x_1+y_1,x_2)$ converge to $f_1(x_1,x_2) = \sin(x_2)$.  Does this make sense?

**Elliptic estimates and PDE**

In PDE the phrase "elliptic estimate" can mean many things, but let's start simply.  Suppose one has a solution to the Poisson equation
$$
\Delta u = f,
$$
and one knows for example that $f\in L^2$.  One might hope to show that $u$ is in the Sobolev space $H^2$ (that is, that its first and second derivatives are in $L^2$), but a priori the only obvious control is over the specific combination of second derivatives that is the Laplacian.  However it turns out to be true that 
$$
\|\partial_{ij} u\|_{L^2} \leq C \|f\|_{L^2} = C\|\Delta u\|_{L^2}.
$$
In general an elliptic estimate is something that controls individual partial derivatives of a function in terms of an elliptic operator acting on the same function.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your time and your answer, even though my question wasn't clear enough! The "$\;f_1\;$ solves the pde" as an additional info , confuses me a lot since the given pde is a system of equations and it is known $\;\Delta f_i-\frac{\partial G}{\partial f_i}\;\forall 1\le i \le m\;$. However you've been very helpful:)

Comment: If this helps, the reason I don't understand your question is that I can't separate the hypotheses from the conclusion.  I imagine you're trying to understand some statement, which is of the form "if X, then Y".  I don't know which part is given (X) and which part you want to show (Y).  If you clarify I may be able to be more specific in my answer.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the conclusion I'm trying to deduce is $\;\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to f_1(x_1,x_2)\;$ as $\;y_1 \to +\infty\;$ in $\;C^3_{loc}\;$. The other statement about $\;f_1\;$ is something additional. Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned it at all. I'll edit my post

Comment: Ok I have a few more points of confusion.  Is $f_1$ the first coordinate of the vector valued $f$?  If that's the case I don't see how the limit can hold.  Another question I have is whether you claim this should be true for any choice of $G$, or do you know something more about $G$?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know $\;G\;$ is arbitary. Now, regarding to $\;f_1\;$      I thought that it might be a typo but it's mentioned also to the statement that I edited just right before so I don't know.. I suppose I should ask my prof

Comment: It makes more sense to me $\;\;f(x_1+y_1,x_2) \to f(x_1,x_2)\;$ instead $\;f_1\;$..